# UIImagePickerControllerでUIImageViewに選択画像が表示されない

Tags: swift

swiftを独学で勉強中の初心者です。ネットの情報など参考にしながら、UIImagePickerControllerのサンプルアプリを作ってみたのですが、カメラロールからの選択画像が、UIImageViewに表示されません。最初は表示されていたのですが、色々試行錯誤をしているうちに、全く表示されなくなりました。原因が全くわかりません。諸先輩の方々、ご指導よろしくお願いいたします。

```
if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary) {

            picker.delegate = self
            picker.allowsEditing = false
            picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary

            picker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext

            present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

            if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                Camview.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                Camview.image = image
            }

            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Comment: `{}` の数が合わない (閉じ括弧が多い) 気がしますが、元のコードも同じでしょうか？

Comment: ご指摘、ありがとうございます。{}の数を修正した所、キチンとimageviewに表示される様になりました。

Comment: 解決したようでなによりです。ここでは [自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) も出来ますのでご検討ください。 / ケアレスミスを防ぐにはコードのインデントを揃える = よいエディタやIDEを使うことをおすすめします。

Comment: 重ね重ね、ありがとうございました。